# Why time Aura input doesnt display values as expected?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-inputfield, time

[image]

Im using lightning inputs for web compononent and for aura lightning

LWC:

```
 <lightning-input data-formfield="Open1" type="time"  variant="label-hidden" value={mondayOpenTime} disabled={mondayOpen}></lightning-input>
```

AURA:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="Open1" variant="label-hidden"  type="time" value="{!v.acc.mondayOpenTime__c}" />
```

Comment: Can you print the values for both? They need to be in ISO format.

Comment: Shure, 09:00:00.000Z. This is the value for monday Open on both components.

Comment: @manjit5190 any idea?